# C++ Cannot convert from Initializer List to std::pair

Tags: c++-cli

I have a function called `TestFunction` which I've simplified down for this question... but in essence, I'm getting an error which says, `<function-style-cast> cannot convert from 'initializer list' to std::pair<int, int>`.  Here's my simplified function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void MyClass::TestFunction(cli::array<int>^ ids){

    std::multimap<int, int> mymap;
    int count = ids->Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        //fill in the multimap with the appropriate data key/values
        mymap.insert(std::make_pair((int)ids[i], (int)i));
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a really basic function (when simplified), but I get an error when I try to insert the data into the multimap.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: You don't have any initializer list in your snippet. Could you post the full error message please?

Comment: C-cli or C++ ? BTW, there are no initializer_list here.

Comment: 1. Did you check you get the same error with this simplified code? 2. What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: I've checked to make sure I get the same error.  I tried updating the code to use std::make_pair() but now I get an error that says that I cannot convert arguement 1 from 'int' to 'int &'.  The error is coming from the line where I try to insert the data into the multimap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd either use

```
mymap.insert(std::make_pair((int)ids[i], (int)i));
```

or

```
mymap.emplace((int)ids[i], (int)i);
```

Comment: if I use: mymap.insert(std::make_pair((int)ids[i], (int)i)); I get an error that says that I cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building off of the answer by @CoryKramer. It appears that if I create a temporary variable of type int and then pass that into the multimap.insert() function... that the error is fixed.  Here's the new function:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <map>

void MyClass::TestFunction(cli::array<int>^ ids){

    std::multimap<int, int> mymap;
    int count = ids->Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        //fill in the multimap with the appropriate data key/values
        int ff = (int)ids[i];
        mymap.insert(std::make_pair(ff, (int)i));
    }
}
```

Out of curiousity... does anyone know why this worked?